# Laravel Bootstrap 4 with tagsinputs

Tags: laravel-5, tags, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get Bootstrap 4 working with tagsinput ([here](https://github.com/Nodws/bootstrap4-tagsinput)). I copied the respective files into the public/js and public/css folder.

I reference them in my Laravel application as follows:

```
  <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.4.0/min/dropzone.min.css">
  @yield('css')


  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
  @yield('scripts');
```

I then use them in my Blade file as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="tags">Tags</label>
   <input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" class="form-control" data-role="tagsinput"/>
</div>
```

Issue is that they are not rendered as tags. They just pop up as an input box

When I investigate the page source, I can confirm that the js and css file are found and they return the content of the js and css file respectively.

Any thoughts?

[image]